# How to link initial points coordinates to corresponding Voronoi vertices coordinates in scipy?

Tags: python, voronoi, scipy-spatial

I use Voronoi from scipy.spatial to draw points and polygons.
Now I need export table/dataframe which link coordinates of initial points to polygon vertices coordinates but I cannot find corresponding formula from attributes (points, vertices, regions etc), can somebody share it ?

Answer (score 1):

From the results of `scipy.spatial.Voronoi`, the association between the input point and the regions of the Voronoi diagram are provided in the `point_region` attribute. Specifically, given the index of an input point, the `point_region` attribute gives the index of the region associated with that point, the `regions` attribute can be used to find indices of the Voronoi vertices associated with the region and then `vertices` attribute can then be used to get the coordinates of the various Voronoi vertices.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
points = np.array([[0, .2], [-.2, 1], [0, 2.1], [1.1, -.1], [1, 1], [0.9, 1.9],[2.2, -0.2], [1.9, 1.1], [2.1, 2.3]])

from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
vor = Voronoi(points)

print("points[4] =", points[4])
print("region for point 4 =", vor.point_region[4])
print("vertices for region for point 4 =", vor.regions[vor.point_region[4]])
print("coordinate of Voronoi vertices associated with point 4:")
print(vor.vertices[vor.regions[vor.point_region[4]]])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = voronoi_plot_2d(vor)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

plt.show()
```

The output from this code is:

```
points[4] = [1. 1.]
region for point 4 = 8
vertices for region for point 4 = [9, 4, 6, 0, 7]
coordinate of Voronoi vertices associated with point 4:
[[1.512      0.492     ]
 [1.4        1.5       ]
 [0.4        1.38888889]
 [0.4        0.725     ]
 [0.64915254 0.41355932]]
```

The Voronoi diagram in the example is shown below: the example is querying information about the Voronoi region in the center.

[image: Example Voronoi Diagram]